# Sharepoint 2010 FullTextSqlQuery using LIKE predicate does not find anything

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to execute a search in SharePoint 2010 with the FullTextSqlQuery class:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
  using (FullTextSqlQuery query = new FullTextSqlQuery(site))
  {
    query.QueryText = "SELECT Title, FooText FROM scope() WHERE FooText = 'Foo2'";
    query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;

    //result output here...
  }
}
```

The SQL statement used above returns some results. But with the following statement, replacing `'='` with `'LIKE'`, no results are returned:

```
SELECT Title, FooText FROM scope() WHERE FooText LIKE 'Foo2'
```

Note: FooText is a Managed Property of type Text and single valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison" option in the settings of the managed property makes the LIKE predicate work.